# Why did the police stop pursuing Karim, given his previous involvement in breaking out OA/Nina?

Tags: the-oa

In S02E04, Karim Washington helps break OA/Nina out of Treasure Island. Afterwards, the police are after both of them.

But in S02E07, he seems to be free to move about: He shows the police around the House, helps admit Fola into the hospital, and even gets blood tested at the hospital. How is this possible? Why is the police no longer after him?